# Combining Regex files in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have 48 .rx.txt files and I'm trying to combine them using Python. I know that when you combine .rx.txt files, you have to include a "|" in between the files.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
import glob

read_files = filter(lambda f: f!='final.txt' and f!='result.txt', glob.glob('*.txt'))


with open("REGEXES.rx.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
            outfile.write('|')
```

But when I try to run that I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kosay.jabre/Desktop/Password Assessor/RegexesNEW/CombineFilesCopy.py", line 10, in <module>
    outfile.write('|')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Any ideas on how I can combine my files into one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `REGEXES.rx.txt` is opened in binary mode, but with `outfile.write('|')` you attempting to write string to it instead of binary. It seems that all of your files contain text data, so instead of opening them as binaries open them as texts, i.e.:

```
with open("REGEXES.rx.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "r") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
            outfile.write('|')
```

Answer (score 0):

In **python2.7.x** your code will work fine, but for **python3.x** you should add **b** prefix to the string `outfile.write(b'|')` that will mark the string as a binary string and then we will be able to write it in a binary file mode.

Then your code for **python3.x** will be:

```
import glob

read_files = filter(lambda f: f!='final.txt' and f!='result.txt', glob.glob('*.txt'))


with open("REGEXES.rx.txt", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())
            outfile.write(b'|')
```

Comment: use this option only if for any reason you need use the binary mode and python3.x otherwise I recommend use solution posted by @Vader that is compatible with **python 2.x and 3.x**

Comment: This worked, but I decided on going with opening as text because I don't really have a reason to open in binary in the first place.